# Find ID/HREF based on current date with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs, addclass

I'm trying to add an active class to the current day in my webapp.

A working example looks like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('a[href*="2208"]').addClass('active');
});
```

I would like to automate the date above (shown as 2208) with moment.js.

As far as I can tell moment.js would output the numbers I want with this code:

```
moment().format("DDMM");
```

So then the question. 
Does anyone know a way of merging this?

Here's a really dumb example (I'm very bad at JS):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('a[href*="moment().format("DDMM");"]').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Concat! `$('a[href*="' + moment().format("DDMM") + '"]').addClass('active');`

Comment: Thanks so much! This works :):)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concat!

```
$('a[href*="' + moment().format("DDMM") + '"]').addClass('active');
```